# Not a valid identifier upon terminal startup

Tags: terminal, bash, path

I am getting this line each time I open my terminal. Everything else seems to be working ok but I would like to get this fixed since I don't think it is a good sign.

```
Last login: Mon Feb 19 09:21:05 on ttys000
-bash: export: `Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin': not a 
valid identifier
Rachels-MacBook-Pro:~ rachelromine$
```

I have checked out my bash_profile and this is what it looks like

```
eval export PATH="/Users/rachelromine/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"
export RBENV_SHELL=bash
source 
'/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash'
command rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null
rbenv() {
  local command
  command="$1"
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    shift
  fi

  case "$command" in
  rehash|shell)
    eval "$(rbenv "sh-$command" "$@")";;
  *)
    command rbenv "$command" "$@";;
  esac
}

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash" && source 
"${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash"
```

I think I must have installed something that when awry. If you have any idea of what I installed that could have caused it that would be extremely helpful but mostly I want to correct the valid identifier issue that appears each time I open my terminal.

Comment: It looks like the root problem is that something's doing an `export` command without properly quoting the value being exported. This might be due to the first line -- the `eval` prefix is useless and dangerous and should be removed. If that doesn't fix it, it's probably in one of the files being `source`d in the third or last lines; you can add `echo` commands (e.g. `echo "about to source rbenv.bash"`) before & after those to find out where the error is coming from.

Comment: You should post this as the answer. removing the eval prefix totally got rid of the not a valid identifier message. Thank you Gordon!!! Do you have any idea on what might have added an eval prefix in there? Or how I might find out?

Comment: klanomath you are right. Here is the actual end
    "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash"
I'm going to correct my original post for completeness

Comment: Upps, sorry, ignore the double rollback, please.

Comment: ??? I'm newish to posting on here can you explain double rollback? Did I do something wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solution (original in comments): remove `eval` from the first line. The problem *could* also have been in either of the scripts that're `source`d (in the third and last lines), but that turned out not to be the case.

Explanation: `eval` makes the shell parse that command twice. Technically, it goes through all the usual steps when the shell parses a command line -- interpreting and removing quotes and escape characters, expanding variables, etc -- then passes the result to the `eval` command as arguments. The `eval` command (which is built into bash, not a separate executable) sticks those arguments back together as though that was a command, runs through all that parsing stuff *again*, and executes the result.

This is almost always a bad idea. Shell parsing is complicated and messy, and doing more of it just makes for more complication and mess. Unfortunately, people sometimes use it as a sort of "hit it with a bigger hammer" solution, and it works about as well as you'd expect beating things with a bigger hammer to work.

In this particular case, I think what's happening is that before this script runs, `PATH` is set to something like "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/Applications/Something Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin" (where "Something" is a different word, but I don't know the specific app name). The shell takes this:

```
eval export PATH="/Users/rachelromine/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"
```

Removes the quotes and expands `${PATH}`, passes the result to `eval`, which executes:

```
export PATH=/Users/rachelromine/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/Applications/Something Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin
```

Since the quotes got removed in the first parsing pass, that space in the middle of the app name is treated as a separator between arguments (rather than as part of a filename), so the `export` command sets `PATH` to "/Users/rachelromine/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/Applications/Something", then in a totally unrelated operation tries to export a variable named "Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin"... which is not a valid variable name ("identifier").

Now, as for what that `eval` is doing there in the first place: I don't know. I can't see how it could possibly do any good here (though if it weren't for the space, it wouldn't have done any harm). I assume it was in some instructions you followed (or a prototype .bash_profile) for installing rbenv. What it was doing *there*, I have no idea.